# Why is there an error when I tried to import pyttsx

Tags: python

I encountered an error when I was importing the module pyttsx. Does anyone have an idea how we can solve this. I have turned on virtuavenv and have pyttsx in my pip, i checked that with pip freeze
the error is: Error: No module found

Comment: Show us the full error and traceback, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install that module firstly and then you can import it successfully.

Try `pip install pyttsx`

**Note:** before running the above command check that the module name is correct or not? Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: He talked about `pyttsx` instead of `pyttsx3`